# jQuery validation not validate after not valid

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Input:

```
<input name="cmp_email" type="text" class="span10 m-wrap">
```

validation:

```
cmp_email: {
  minlength: 5,
  required: true,
  email: true,

  remote: {
    url: "\/client\/check-email",
    type: "post"
  },
},
```

Validation work fine until I not insert existing email, after I change this email to not existing, but validation show, that this email exist, but php function returning true

```
public function  checkEmailAction(){

  $email = $_POST;

  //echo 'true';
  try{
    foreach($email as $m){

      if($this->client_emails->emailCount($m)){

        echo 'false';
        die();
      }
    }

    foreach($email['cl_email'] as $m){

      if($this->client_emails->emailCount($m)){

        echo 'false';
        die();
      }

    }
  }

  catch(Exception $e){

}

  echo 'true';
  mail('tomas@example.lt','after true',print_r($_POST,true));
  die();
}
```

I'm getting email with subject "after true" but validation showing that this email exists. PHP function works fine, something wrong is with jQuery, when change existing email to not exist but jquery say that email exists.

Comment: There is nothing you've shown that will give a _"example@gmail.com exists"_ message.  In other words, the example you've shown us is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set email cache to false

```
  email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                 url: "\/client\/check-email",
                 type: "post",
                cache: false
            }
        },
```

Comment: This also not help for me.

Comment: try to change the type of your input ( type='email' )

Comment: where are you storing existing emails , mysql database ?

Comment: Yes in mysql database, but with function is ok, function returning corect ansver.

Comment: i really didn't understand your check email action method but i can provide you with an example i have already worked with . check my answer .

Comment: I think problem is in cache, because, I change email but error get same "example@gmail.com" exist, when change to example1@gmail.com get also error "k problem is in cache, because, I change email but error get same "example@gmail.com" exist "